# filling in laterally discontinuous contours in a 3d numpy array with unique values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, image-processing

I have a 3d numpy array with x, y, and depth as the dimensions. This is binary array that contains labels for various objects. These labels are currently not unique (all objects are labeled at 1s), but the objects they represent are unique from each other irl. I've taken the binary array and extracted contours around each object. My goal is to assign unique values to each contour area.

For a simple 2d example of this i'll create a numpy array with laterally discontinuous contours, similar to the real data:

```
countour_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                           [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
```

and the matplotlib plot for `contour_array` for easy viewing:

[image: input]

and this would be the expected output:

```
mask_array = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                       [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [2,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                       [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                       [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
                       [3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]])
```

and the matplotlib plot for `mask_array` for easy viewing:

[image: output]

you can see that there are 4 unique objects that need to be labeled. label #2 is embedded within label #1 and laterally discontinuous in the x direction. label #1 also stops when reaching label #3.

**edit:** boundary values need to have the same value as the filled value below. see mask array image.

[image: real_data] above is a 2d binary array showing the contours i extracted from the actual dataset. As you can see, these contours are not always continuous in the x space.

**What I've tried**

*My first attempt* at this was iterating through each column in the data, applying `.cumsum()` to generate unique values, then using `push()` to forward fill the data down each column. see code below:

```
# create an empty array for the labels
mask_array = np.zeros_like(contour_array)
# determine shape of data for iteration
xx, yy, d = contour_array.shape
# loop through 3d array
for x in range(xx):
    for y in range(yy):
        # apply cumsum() to assign unique values to each object
        mask_array[x,y,:] = contour_array[x,y,:].cumsum()*contour_array[x,y,:]
        # replace zeros with nulls for for forward fill
        mask_array[x,y,:] = np.where(mask_array[x,y,:] == 0, np.nan, mask_array[x,y,:])
        # apply push to each column to create labels
        mask_array[x,y,:] = push(mask_array[x,y,:])
        # fill remaining nulls with 0
        mask_array[np.isnan(mask_array)] = 0.0
```

While my code is probably slow, this would work if the objects, or layers, were continuous in the x space, but because they are discontinuous the output is choppy and misses the changes between embedded objects and continuous layers.

*My second attempt* was to apply a moving window with numpy `sliding_window_view()` with the code above to try and capture the lateral changes. i wasn't really able to get this operational and the code is not good.

*Finally*, i've been researching using `cv2.fillPoly()`, but not sure this is the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple flood fill to label the bulk of each object and then clean up the border values afterwards.

```py
import skimage.segmentation

newval = countour_array.max() + 1
for idx in np.ndindex(countour_array.shape):
    if countour_array[idx] == 0:
        skimage.segmentation.flood_fill(countour_array, idx, newval,
                                        connectivity=1, in_place=True)
        newval += 1

# assign the border values to the object directly below
for idx in np.ndindex(countour_array.shape):
    if countour_array[idx] == 1:
        assert idx[0] < countour_array.shape[0]
        countour_array[idx] = countour_array[idx[0]+1, idx[1]]

# normalize object IDs so they start at zero
countour_array -= 2
```

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: thanks for the help Woodford. The issue still seems to be that the embedded object in your answer (the 1s inside values 3) should be filled with with a different label. also, i've edited my question to include your question about boundaries. the boundaries should have the same values as the fill

Comment: Same value as *which* fill? The value at (0, 2) could be either a 2 or a 3 (in my example).

Comment: in your example the value at (0,2) should be 3. the same as the values in the row below. so at (0,9) in your example the value would be 4.

Comment: Edited to include your description of how the border values should be handled.

Comment: this works fairly well on a 2d array, but when using on a 3d array (x,y,z) we are unable to resolve the mask in 3d. for example, we have two cross section lines at x=5 and y=5. in this method horizon #2 is likely different on the x line and the y lines. how do you resolve the fill in 3 dimensions?